# tensorflow.keras like imports show warnings in PyCharm, work well on command line

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

[image: The Error in PyCharm]

I get this error when I import modules from TensorFlow in PyCharm.

> Cannot find reference 'keras' in '**init**.py'

But when I use the `tensorflow.python.keras` prefix, the warning is not shown. Also, in the command line, no such warning is shown.

```
>> from tensorflow.keras import activations
>> # No errors!
```

How can I fix that warning in PyCharm and freely use `tensorflow.keras` and not `tensorflow.python.keras`? I'm using Windows 10, TF version 1.12.0 installed using Anaconda and PyCharm 2018.2.5.

Comment: I created an issue in PyCharm's bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34174

Comment: This is fixed in 2019.3 _(currently in EAP)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After tensorflow gobbled keras, there were problem with `tf.keras` imports on IDEs although the code works.This was then raised an as issue ([Issue #26502](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26502))

> It seems that there is no import command for keras module in `__init_.py` of tensorflow package.
>   When I added from tensorflow.python import keras to `__init__.py` manually, everything work well.
>   Maybe there are some problem for package importing after keras was moved from `_api` to python.

As of tensorflow 2.0, even `from tensorflow.python import keras` wouldn't work: basically there is no way of making PyCharm / IDEA help you with syntax. However, **this issue is fixed in IDEA 2019.3+** *(currently in EAP, so should be in PyCharm EAP)*

Comment: Sadly, it's not fixed anymore.